# PHP: Make sure legacy scripts run without errors, replacement for `php_check_syntax`

Tags: php, automated-tests, end-to-end

I have a lot of legacy code which doesn't have unit tests. For the most part they are stand-alone scripts with autoloaded classes, run by executing each individual .php file directly.

I would like to have some method to automate the running of these scripts, checking that they run to completion without errors. This would not only detect faulty new code, but automagically find which scripts are running with errors (without trying to parse the error logs).

I saw `php_check_syntax` but it is deprecated. It seems preferable to `php -l` because it doesn't just lint - it executes the scripts, and would seem to capture the run-time errors to a variable which can then be read. And this seems exactly like what I'd like to do.

Is there a replacement for the `php_check_syntax` which will help me accomplish this?

Comment: please leave a comment if you're downvoting. I'm not asking for a suggestion of a library.

Comment: How are the .php files being executed exactly?

Comment: Usually via an http request. But I'd like to run them in the background (using curl or php-cli) and check for run-time errors that way.

Comment: The probably with executing files now is that it depends on a lot more factors than just the standalone file. You may want to create a script that runs through test cases, and then set up a cron schedule to execute that script.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a wrapper that uses `try` and `catch` blocks?

Comment: @aynber true - though by executing the standalone all the includes and loaded classes would be tested?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah - no, that is an interesting suggesting and may well work. Thank you.

Comment: If you're using PHP 7, @RaphaelRafatpanah is right on track here just use a `try` and a `catch` block. In PHP 7 there is a specific [parseerror](http://php.net/manual/en/class.parseerror.php) exception.

Comment: @Xorifelse - that's very good to know, thank you. Though I am sort of specifically looking to catch run-time errors. But the Try-Catch should still work in that case. Try Catch, and maybe some variable being set that denotes that the script ran to a certain point.

Comment: @DanFromGermany not sure what you're talking about. I stated I'm not looking for a  book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource but a PHP method to replace a deprecated function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps creating a wrapper that uses `try` and `catch` (and `finally`) blocks would work.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: I will test this and let you know. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I accepted Raphael's answer. It was correct way to go about this. I'm posting the full script created from it here.

It is run from the command line with:

`php scripttest.php "http://example.com/?param1=test"` and will exit with code 9 on any errors. It will pick up parse errors using the `php -l` command and also exceptions using a Try Catch block. It won't detect if a script exits early. That would have to be detected by checking for an empty output.

```
<?php

$url = $argv[1];
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);

if(!$url || $parsed_url == false){
    echo "Provided url is empty or malformed.";
    exit(9);
}

$docroot = "/Library/WebServer/Webs";
if    ($parsed_url['scheme'] == "https") $docroot .= "/example.com-https";
elseif($parsed_url['scheme'] == "http")  $docroot .= "/example.com";
else{
    echo "Couldn't detect protocol.";
    exit(9);
}

$filepath = $docroot.$parsed_url['path'];
if(is_dir($filepath)) $filepath .= 'index.php';

if(!file_exists($filepath)){
    echo "Filepath doesn't exist.";
    exit(9);
}

/**
 * lint
 */
$success_str = "No syntax errors detected";
$output      = array();
exec("php -l $filepath", $output);

if(!$output){
    echo "linting exec produced no output.";
    exit(9);
}
$success = (substr($output[0], 0, strlen($success_str)) === $success_str);
if(!$success){
    echo join("\n", $output);
    exit(9);
}


/**
 * run-time check
 */
$_REQUEST = parse_str ($parsed_url['query']);

try{

    $finished      = false;
    $has_exception = false;
    $exception     = '';

    ob_start();        // buffer all output
    require $filepath; // execute script
    ob_end_clean();    // wipe buffer

    $finished      = true;

}catch(Exception $e){

    $has_exception = true;
    $exception     = $e->getMessage();
}

if($finished && !$has_exception){
    echo "SUCCESS";
    exit(0);
}else{
    echo "Failed with exception $exception";
    exit(9);
}
```